# Can't set and display a QTabelView Horizontal Header

Tags: c++, qt, model, qtableview

I'm developing a Qt Application using Qt Creator and I've placed a `QTableView` on a `QDialog`.

My `QTableView` objectName is `tvStock`.

I would like `tvStock` to have three columns with the following horizontal headers: `Stock ID`, `Description` and `Price`.

I have no idea how to add these horizontal headers. Any help would be much appreciated!

**Additional Notes:**

I'm not sure how to use `QTableView::setHorizontalHeader`.

This is as far as I get with that:

```
ui->tvStock->setHorizontalHeader(/* I'm lost here */);
```

Comment: Look at [QTableView::setHorizontalHeader(...)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setHorizontalHeader).

Comment: I see that but I'm nor sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's the model that's supplying the data it should really be the model that provides the column labels.

Assuming the model isn't read only you should be able to use [`QAbstractItemModel::setHeaderData`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setHeaderData) with something like...

```
my_model.setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, "Stock ID", Qt::DisplayRole);
my_model.setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, "Description", Qt::DisplayRole);
my_model.setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, "Price", Qt::DisplayRole);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for me even though I'm using `QStandardItemModel`